# C# (Visual Studio \ Unity) - Changing variables location and all of its references

Tags: c#

I have a question
Assuming you have to following class

```
public class Country 
{
  public long Population { get; private set;}
  public int NumberOfCities { get; private set;}
}
```

Population and NumberOfCities are used in many other scripts in the project
And I want to implement a new class inside country called Data (for serialization purposes)

```
public class Country 
{
  [serializable]
  public class Data
  {
    public long Population { get; private set;}
    public int NumberOfCities { get; private set;}
  }
  public Data data;
}
```

After doing it I required to go over all the references for Population and NumberOfCities and add data.Population / data.NumberOfCities and change each one of them (can take for ever espcially when we have a lot of refernces in other scripts), is there any shortcut of doing it ? (this is simple example with two variables but we trying to understand how to do it for a lot of variables simultaneously)

Thanks in advance :)

I tried searching for solution online for didnt found anything

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct shortcut for this, but you can try to Replace All feature.

First press Ctrl + Shift + f, it will the window like the one below.

then select Replace in Files.

Then select the option as per your requirement.

You can replace them one by one and Replace all.

But again you have to be careful while replacing, you cannot go and blindly replace all.

If your project is under any version control then your task will be easy because you could be easily able to see the difference of the changes done

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot ! 
Is there any way to do it on both Population and NumberOfCities in one session ?

Comment: do it one by one.